# Blue Prism application modeler launch not working for Windows 10

Tags: blueprism

I created an object to launch a website in `Internet Explorer`, but when I hit the `launch button` in `Application Modeler` I get this error:

> Error - Failed to launch application - There are no more files.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070012)

I had a co-worker try the object on their laptop and the website launched fine, so it doesn't seem like there's an issue with the object. I'm running `Windows 10 Enterprise`, they are running `Windows 7 Enterprise`. I searched the `Blue Prism Portal` and tried their recommendations for `Windows 10`, such as changing the display settings, etc.  This didn't fix the issue.

Doesn't make a difference it `IE` is open or not.

Has anyone else had this issue?  Any ideas how to fix?

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 1):

I got it resolved after I changed the TabProcGrowth value for 'local machine' from 0 to Medium. Kept the TabProcGrowth value for the user (not the local machine) to 0 as suggested by BluePrism.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that it's some kind of issue with the current build and update on your windows 10 machine. We had a similar problems here with the Windows 10 "Creators Update" that was fixed in the next windows patch. Would you mind installing all the updates from windows update first?

Some people on the internet are reporting that this error happens because of KB4022725 and [ASUS data security management](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files-winpc/error-message-there-are-no-more-files/845c1239-0e3e-4ea7-84fb-a0ec53d89663). My next advice would be to try to remove one or another.